# awk - print only first line of duplicates and the line below it

Tags: database, linux, command-line, awk, matching

I have a large database file that needs some manipulation.  Essentially I need to avoid duplicate field one delimited by '|' for:

```
-- TITLE1 | TITLE2   |T3   |TITLE4|TITLE5 
----------|----------|-----|------|---------------
--
DATA1   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | x1 
DATA1   | SAME     |     | blah |  blah
ELIGIBLE  | x2 
DATA1   | SAME     |     | blah |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | x2 
DATA2   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | y1 
DATA2   | SAME     |     | blah |  blah
ELIGIBLE  | y2
DATA2   | SAME     |     | blah |  blah blah blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | y2
DATA3   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | z1
DATA3   | SAME     |     | blah |  blah
ELIGIBLE  | z2
DATA3   | SAME     |     | blah |  blah blah blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | z2
```

The code I am using is

```
BEGIN{ FS = "|" }
{
count[$1]++;
if (count[$1] == 1)
first [$1] = $0;
if (count[$1] > 1)
print first[$1]
NR==1;
}
```

But it gives me the output:

```
-- TITLE1 | TITLE2   |T3   |TITLE4|TITLE5 
----------|----------|-----|------|---------------
--
DATA1   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | x1 
DATA2   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
DATA3   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
```

I would prefer an output like this:

```
-- TITLE1 | TITLE2   |T3   |TITLE4|TITLE5 
----------|----------|-----|------|---------------
--
DATA1   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | x1 
DATA2   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | y1 
DATA3   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | z1
```

I don't really care about the title block but need it to show the data as outlined.  Sorry for the amateurish explanation but any help for a solution would be appreciated.  I am a novice when it comes to linux command line scripting so if any one could also explain why my answer is wrong, I would be much appreciated.  I am not limited to awk, and can use any command solution. I just wanted to try the solution with awk.

Comment: So you want to keep the first line of data with a given TITLE1 and throw away the rest, even when they have different TITLE5's etc?

Comment: correct, and to keep the eligible line below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
awk -F\| '(printed!=0 && /ELIGIBLE/) {print; printed=0;} (!seen[$1] && $1 !~ /ELIGIBLE/) { print; printed = 1; seen[$1] = 1;  }'
```

Although there's almost certainly a better way.

**ETA:** There's a good Awk tutorial [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and several others around the web, along with some good books.  But basically, an awk program is a series of patterns and blocks of code to run on every record (line, by default) that matches that pattern.

```
awk '/foo/          { do this for lines that contain "foo" anywhere }
     ($1 == "bar")  { do this for lines whose first field is exactly "bar' }
     ($NF ~ /baz/)  { do this for lines whose last field contains "baz" }
     (NF == 1)      { do this for lines with exactly one field }
     (NR == 10)     { do this only on the 10th line }'
```

If there's no pattern, the block runs on every line.

```
awk '{print $NF}'   # print the last field of every line
```

If there's no block and just a pattern, then matching lines are printed unchanged:

```
awk '/foo/'      # same as grep foo
```

A block labeled BEGIN is run before any input is processed; a block labeled END is run after all input is processed.

```
awk 'BEGIN { t = 0 } {t += $NF} END { print t }'   # print total of last column
```

but actually uninitialized variables are treated as 0 in arithmetic, so you can skip the initialization:

```
awk '{t += $NF} END {print t}'
```

Some versions of awk require a semicolon `;` or newline between pattern/block pairs

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thank you so much! Could you explain how you exclude/include text using awk.  Sorry I am learning and have only used it for field matching.

Answer (score 0):

This line works for your given example. (the data are sorted, oneline data, oneline Eligible...) No guarantee of working for your real data, if the format changes. You have to test it by yourself.

title/header is skipped.

```
awk -F'|' '!(NR%2){next}$1 in a{next}{print;a[$1];getline;print}' file
```

try it:

```
kent$  awk -F'|' '!(NR%2){next}$1 in a{next}{print;a[$1];getline;print}' file
DATA1   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | x1 
DATA2   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | y1 
DATA3   | SAME     |     |      |  blah blah
ELIGIBLE  | z1
```